# AlarmManager not going off at correct time

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, timepicker

I am creating an app that uses a TimePicker that the user sets a time that they want an SMS sent to a specified number. They also have the option to click repeat so that the SMS will continue to be sent at that same specified time every day.

My issue is that it is just going off immediately after I set the timer instead of waiting. I have tried to mess with the intervals many times but logically it seems like it should be working as is, but it doesn't.

Here is the code for getting the time from the time picker and setting the AlarmManger:

```
Button setSchedule = (Button) setTimer.findViewById(R.id.setSchedule);
setSchedule.setText("Set");
setSchedule.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        hours = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
        minutes = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
        minutesConv += hours * 60;
        minutes += minutesConv;
        seconds = minutes * 60;
        time = seconds * 1000;
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        CheckBox repeat = (CheckBox) setTimer.findViewById(R.id.repeat);

        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(MainMenu.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainMenu.this, 0, intentAlarm, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if (repeat.isChecked())
        {
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time - currentTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
        }//end if
        else
        {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,  time - currentTime,  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainMenu.this, 1, intentAlarm,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        }//end else

        Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Your message has been scheduled to be repeated at " +
                                    hours + ":" + minutes, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setTimer.dismiss();
    }//end onClick

});
```

EDIT:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(0, 0, 0, timePicker.getCurrentHour(), timePicker.getCurrentMinute(), 00);
Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "time: " + cal.getTimeInMillis(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
CheckBox repeat = (CheckBox) setTimer.findViewById(R.id.repeat);

Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(MainMenu.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainMenu.this, 0, intentAlarm, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

if (repeat.isChecked())
{
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, pi);
}//end if
else
{
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),  PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainMenu.this, 1, intentAlarm,
                                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
}//end else
```

Comment: See the current answer. time - currentTime will typically set an alarm in the past, which causes the alarm to be triggered immediately.

Comment: Yes. . . note, (currentTime - time) would have been better (though still wrong). You just got lucky that (time - currentTime) would be in the past since currentTime is typically a pretty large number. Also, your calculation of time is flawed. It only includes *minutes* and *seconds* - it doesn't include the value from *hours*.

Comment: @iheanyi I have a value for hours, its just getting the current hours set on the TimePicker. Then i convert it to minutes.

Comment: Looks like you updated your code to add a line that says "minutes += minutesConv;" That wasn't there when I made my comment.

Comment: @iheanyi Yes I updated that. The alarm still does not trigger at the time I am wanting though.

Comment: I think you still don't quite understand. You set the alarm for currentTime +  how many milliseconds into the future you want your alarm to take place. So, if my HHMMSS is 01:10:15 - currentTime + time means my alarm will take place 1 hour, 10 minutes, and 15 seconds into the future, not at 01:10:15 AM.

Comment: Also, your code still has an issue computing time. You have minuteConv += hours * 60. Then minutes += minuteConv and seconds = minute * 60

So, say hours = 1 and minutes = 5. If minuteConv starts at 0, minuteConv = 0 + 1*60. minutes updates to 5 + 60. Then seconds to 65 * 60 = 3900.

Then, if you set the timer again with the exact same values, minuteConv = 3900 + 1 * 60 = 3960. minutes = 5 + 3960. Seconds = 3960 * 60 = 237600.

Comment: @iheanyi I know what currentTime + time means. That's why I have it for my set() method of the alarmManager. It does not trigger at the right time though even though the logic that you are describing is what I am wanting. I understand that the setRepeating() method will be different, but I will figure that out when we get there.

Comment: So then the time that the user selects is really how far into the future they want the alarm to go off and not WHEN they want it to go off correct? If not, it means you are incorrectly setting the alarm time.

Comment: @iheanyi Ah I am misunderstanding you. I am sorry. I do want it to set the alarm to trigger at the time that the user sets the TimePicker to which makes me think that I would need to find the difference between the current time and the time they set it to so I took time - currentTime. That doesn't work though so I though i would take that difference and add it back to the current time to get the time that i needed, but that is redundant, subtracting a number and then just adding right back in.

Comment: Look at this page. The section under RTC examples shows how to use a calendar object to compute the correct value to use if you want to set an alarm for a specific time. Then you don't have to worry about doing any calculations at all: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue has to do with correct setting of an alarm. Essentially, the alarm manager is set to the absolute time in milliseconds when you want the alarm to trigger. You have a couple options to compute this.

1. Use the method in your code where you take the value the user inputs and compute a delta from the currentTime in milliseconds. This is useful when the user specifies that they want an alarm X amount of time into the future.
2. Use the calendar method described under the RTC examples here: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html
   This allows users to specify a time or full date for the alarm and you just get the millisecond value directly from the calendar object.

Try this for your calendar to set a single alarm:

```
hours = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
minutes = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainMenu.this, 1, intentAlarm,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

The setTimeInMillis() updates the calendar object to the current date (so year and all that other stuff is setup correctly). Then, you set the calendar to the future time on the same day and pass it to the alarm manager.

Comment: By using the calendar object I get a negative value for the time. I added my code using Calendar

Comment: I have looked into how apparently the year will be off and should be set to 1970 or something but nothing I see is clear. Adding 1970 or any other year i have seen has not helped regardless.

Comment: You should have used the example from the link I gave you. It perfectly matches what you need and automatically sets the year.

Comment: @saboehnke I've updated my answer to have example code for you to use. That plus the link in the answer should show you how to handle the recurring alarm case.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) correctly, the `triggerAtMillis` parameter is the absolute, not relative time. Passing `time + currentTime` instead of `time - currentTime` should be fine.

Comment: I have tried that and then the alarm just doesn't go off at all. Either that or it is going off way later than it should.

Comment: Were you setting the alarm in the near future? Check what all of the inputs are. Also check the code for what you are expecting to happen after the alarm goes off, it wasn't included in the bit you posted.

Comment: Yes I would only set this for a couple minutes for testing. The SMS part is working fine. The message is sent just fine, its just not happening when I am wanting it to.

Comment: I feel like something could be wrong with your callback for the alarm then, maybe looking at `https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html` will help you find the issue. You could update your original question with that code that reacts to the alarm going off as well.

Comment: That is the documentation I used to do this in the first place. I have looked all over the place but nothing seems to explain my issue.

Comment: I have noticed that the message does send when I am testing, it just like 15 minutes later. I don't know how I am using the time incorrectly though.

Comment: You are probably not setting your alarm time correctly. You need to add to the currentTime the amount of milliseconds into the future that you want the alarm to trigger.